# RS232 for iOS device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, serial-port, serial-communication

Is it possible to pair an iDevice to an rs232-bluetooth adapter for the purpose of sending serial commands like it would through an iDevice dock connector to rs232 (just like the Redpark Serial Cable does)?  I ask because the company I work for is thinking of having an iDevice control one of our systems for demo.  I know it doesn't relate to anything specific but any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

(See also [iPhone to RS-232 via Bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420717/iphone-to-rs-232-via-bluetooth))

Bluetooth modules exists that support MFi (Made For iPhone) such as this one from connectBlue http://www.connectblue.com/products/bluetooth-products/bluetooth-modules/bluetooth-iphone-ios-accessory-module-obs414/  So the standard iPhone Bluetooth stack can make a SPP/RFCOMM connection to that device.  That device could be added to a board along with RS232 level-conversion etc...  And thus success.

I don't know whether someone sells such a device.  The RS232 device that connectBlue sells seems not to support MFi, http://www.connectblue.com/products/bluetooth-products/bluetooth-devices/bluetooth-rugged-serial-port-adapter-rbs433/

Answer (score 2):

Not really. The GameKit is one way to access bluetooth in iOS, but it is very limited in what that API allows you to do. 
Depending on what you are building, you might be able to use the Apple Made for iPod program, but it's probably a long shot. 
http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

Comment: We tried to go with MFI and got rejected by Apple.  Don't know why, I just overheard about the rejection.  I guess I will see if GameKit can even help at all.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go is probably to design a device that connects via WiFi. I've gone this route, and it worked out well. If you must interface with something with an RS-232 interface, you might design an intermediary "adapter" that connects via WiFi to the iOS device, and via RS-232 to the other device.

If you don't have a need to distribute your app via the App Store, you can use Redpark's iOS serial cable: http://redpark.com/c2db9.html. (Disclaimer, I've never tried one, but according to someone at Redpark, jailbreaking is not required, you just can't distribute your app on the app store.)

Comment: I have actually used this cable before.  Now we are trying to go wireless.

Comment: OK. Like I said, we had good success with a WiFi-capable device talking to the iPhone with no need for the MFi program. However, the WiFi device itself was a completely custom design, not something off the shelf.

Answer (score 0):

You could design a small dongle that attaches via the dock connector, and broadcasts over bluetooth to your other device.

Or you could use WiFi instead of bluetooth... perhaps communicating over WiFi to something that's physically plugged into whatever you want to control.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a jailbroken app which used [BTStack](http://code.google.com/p/btstack/) to communicate with a serial device. You might be able to use this for your demo.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking to use bluetooth, this helped me out alot to facilitate the standard serial connection for prototyping without jailbreaking:

http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/bleshield-based-on-bluegigas-ble112-module-p-1367.html

It works on the Bluetooth 4.0 enabled iOS devices and all of the schematic, boardfiles, firmware sources and the iOS App sources are available here:

https://github.com/michaelkroll/BLE-Shield