# iOS Core Bluetooth Serial Port

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, obd-ii

Given I have a bluetooth device which returns some serial data - how do I read it using CoreBluetooth?

There is no Characteristics or Services. Just some binary data in known (actually obd ii) format.

Comment: That's weird. A Bluetooth Low Energy device should have services and characteristic. Are you sure it use Bluetooth Low Energy, or just "classical" Bluetooth?

Comment: I'm also trying to do the same. However my peripheral isn't a device. It's a Windows program running on Windows 7 which simulates OBD II data through a COM port via BLE. But my iOS app doesn't detect it.

Answer (score 0):

I think iOS blocks the access to the serial port over bluetooth.

You might need to buy extra hardware, use WiFi, or jailbreak it.

[RS232 for iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736632/rs232-for-ios-device?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [roqyOBD](http://www.roqy-bluetooth.net/wp/) if you manage to jailbreak your iPhone. I believe that it creates a TCP server that you can use [FuzzyLuke's OBD2Kit](https://github.com/FuzzyLuke/OBD2Kit) and thus read the PID's that are sent from the OBD-II interface to the iPhone.

Let me know how it goes! I myself am tinkering OBD-II with iPhone and am learning just like you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a Bluetooth 2.0 or 3.0 device which is not BTLE compliant. CoreBluetooth is an implementation of BTLE, hence you can't use said device on (non-jailbroken) iOS. There are a lot of BTLE compliant devices these days, so better get one of those, if you want to interface with iOS.